# How do I find the total number of used days in a month?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am arriving at the total number of days a service has been used in a month.
(Start_Date and End_Date are - both inclusive)

Sample Data 1:

```
User  Start_Date     End_Date
A     01-Jun-2017    30-Jun-2017
B     06-Jun-2017    30-Jun-2017
```

Ans: Service used days = 30 days.

Sample Data 2:

```
User  Start_Date     End_Date
C     06-Jun-2017    10-Jun-2017
D     02-Jun-2017    02-Jun-2017
```

Ans: Service used days = 6 days.

How do I write a code to find the same, preferable in SQL to PLSQL.

Comment: can you explain the logic needed?

Comment: Didnt understand logic to derive (service used days). Sample data for user 'A' is 30 days but for B its 25 days. In your question you have just mentioned 30'

Comment: from what you explain it's a basic difference between end-date and start_date, or it's not explained correctly.
    select user, (end_date - start_date) as "Service Used" from table.

Comment: Are the start_date and end_date always in the month you are interested in? Or can you have start_date = 29-May-2017, end_date = 03-Jun-2017, covering three days in June? If these are possible, the question is more interesting. Also: is there another column that shows WHAT is in use (perhaps which piece of equipment, or which room, etc.) - and does the solution need to get you the answer BY PIECE OF EQUIPMENT or BY ROOM etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Test Data**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( usr, start_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2017-06-01', DATE '2017-06-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2017-06-02', DATE '2017-06-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Overlaps previous
  SELECT 'C', DATE '2017-06-06', DATE '2017-06-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D', DATE '2017-06-07', DATE '2017-06-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Adjacent to previous
  SELECT 'E', DATE '2017-06-11', DATE '2017-06-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'F', DATE '2017-06-14', DATE '2017-06-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Within previous
  SELECT 'G', DATE '2017-06-22', DATE '2017-06-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'H', DATE '2017-06-24', DATE '2017-06-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Overlaps previous and next
  SELECT 'I', DATE '2017-06-27', DATE '2017-06-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'J', DATE '2017-06-27', DATE '2017-06-28' FROM DUAL;          -- Within H and I
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT SUM( days ) AS total_days
FROM   (
  SELECT dt - LAG( dt ) OVER ( ORDER BY dt ) + 1 AS days,
         start_end
  FROM   (
    SELECT dt,
           CASE SUM( value ) OVER ( ORDER BY dt ASC, value DESC, ROWNUM ) * value
             WHEN 1 THEN 'start'
             WHEN 0 THEN 'end'
           END AS start_end
    FROM   your_table
    UNPIVOT ( dt FOR value IN ( start_date AS 1, end_date AS -1 ) )
  )
  WHERE start_end IS NOT NULL
)
WHERE start_end = 'end';
```

**Output**:

```
TOTAL_DAYS
----------
        25
```

**Explanation**:

```
SELECT dt, value
FROM   your_table
UNPIVOT ( dt FOR value IN ( start_date AS 1, end_date AS -1 ) )
```

This will `UNPIVOT` the table so that the start and end dates are in the same column (`dt`) and are given a corresponding value of +1 for a start and -1 for an end date.

```
SELECT dt,
       SUM( value ) OVER ( ORDER BY dt ASC, value DESC, ROWNUM ) AS total,
       value
FROM   your_table
UNPIVOT ( dt FOR value IN ( start_date AS 1, end_date AS -1 ) )
```

Will give the start and end dates and the cumulative sum of those generated values. The start of a range will always have `value=1` and `total=1` and the end of a range will always have `total=0`. If a date is mid-way through a range then it will either have `total>1` or `value=-1` and `total=1`. Using this, if you multiply `value` and `total` then the start of a range is when `value*total=1` and the end of a range is when `value*total=0` and any other value indicates a date that is midway through a range.

Which is what this gives:

```
SELECT dt,
       CASE SUM( value ) OVER ( ORDER BY dt ASC, value DESC, ROWNUM ) * value
         WHEN 1 THEN 'start'
         WHEN 0 THEN 'end'
       END AS start_end
FROM   your_table
UNPIVOT ( dt FOR value IN ( start_date AS 1, end_date AS -1 ) )
```

You can then filter out the dates when the `start_end` is `NULL` which will leave you with a table with alternating `start` and `end` rows which you can use `LAG` to calculate the number of days difference:

```
SELECT dt - LAG( dt ) OVER ( ORDER BY dt ) + 1 AS days,
       start_end
FROM   (
  SELECT dt,
         CASE SUM( value ) OVER ( ORDER BY dt ASC, value DESC, ROWNUM ) * value
           WHEN 1 THEN 'start'
           WHEN 0 THEN 'end'
         END AS start_end
  FROM   your_table
  UNPIVOT ( dt FOR value IN ( start_date AS 1, end_date AS -1 ) )
)
WHERE start_end IS NOT NULL
```

All you need to do then is to `SUM` all the differences for the `end - start`; which gives the query above.

Comment: You understood my requirement perfectly @MT0. The test case could not be better. Thanks champ.

Comment: Hey, can you help me to make the code work with the following data:
(the start and/or end date of two rows are the same) 
SET 1:
    A   1-Jun-2017  3-Jun-2017
    B   1-Jun-2017  2-Jun-2017
Result:NULL
Expected result:3

SET 2:
    A   1-Jun-2017  3-Jun-2017
    B   1-Jun-2017  3-Jun-2017
Result:1
Expected result:3

Comment: @Raghu Updated - good catch on those cases. Just need to add `ROWNUM` to the `ORDER BY` clause of the inner most `SUM` so that the value is calculated per row (and not grouped for same dates and start/end value).

Answer (score 1):

As @Pravin Satav addressed, your requirement it's not very clear, something like this is what I understood from your explanation:

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN end_date=start_date THEN 1 ELSE (end_date-start_date)+1 END) as total_days
FROM my_table
WHERE <conditions that determine your "sample data">;
```

Comment: This does not account for double counting days when two (or more) ranges overlap.

Comment: Must be that one can't make that clear from requirement stated in OP.

Comment: Well the OP states in the Sample Data 1 example that the result should be 30 days - your answer would give 30+25=55 days.

Comment: Just as @Pravin Satav pointed out in early post comments, that exact point created a doubt, and was never clarified by author.