# Calculate Free / Available Days Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which works like a hotel system and contains check in and check out dates.
What I want to do here is, I want to see how many days are available / free in a month.
For example;

| Name | Check_In | Check_Out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joey Zolomon | 05/08/2023 | 15/08/2023 |
| Hunter Zolomon | 15/08/2023 | 26/08/2023 |
| Barry Allen | 02/09/2023 | 05/09/2023 |

I need output to look like this;

| Month | Free_Days |
| --- | --- |
| 08/2023 | 8 |
| 09/2023 | 26 |

Thanks everyone in advance!!!

Comment: Please show your current code and describe what is the issue with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: @astentx That link is not really relevant to this question. [SQL counting days with gap / overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48531322/1509264) is more relevant but even that is not a duplicate as that is asking for days when something does happen and this is asking for days when nothing happens (and to also split on months).

Comment: Does Check_In 02/09/2023 and Check_Out 05/09/2023 really count as 4 days? Someone else should be able to checkin 05/09/2023, so I'd say it's only 3 days. (If you only have one-night stays, every second night, the difference will become obvious.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option; read comments within code:

```
SQL> with
  2  test (name, check_in, check_out) as
  3    -- this is your sample table
  4    (select 'Joey Zolomon'  , date '2023-08-05', date '2023-08-15'   from dual union all
  5     select 'Hunter Zolomon', date '2023-08-15', date '2023-08-26'   from dual union all
  6     select 'Barry Allen'   , date '2023-09-02', date '2023-09-05'   from dual
  7    ),
  8  checked as
  9    -- non-available dates
 10    (select check_in + column_value - 1 datum
 11     from test cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                                              connect by level <= check_out - check_in + 1
 13                                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 14    ),
 15  calendar as
 16    -- calendar for the whole year
 17    (select trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') + level - 1 datum
 18     from dual
 19     connect by level <= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), 12) - trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy')
 20    ),
 21  available as
 22    -- available dates are calculated as [all days in a year] MINUS [all non-available dates]
 23    (select k.datum from calendar k
 24     minus
 25     select c.datum from checked c
 26    )
 27  -- finally, aggregate number of free (available) dates per every month
 28  select to_char(a.datum, 'mm') month,
 29    count(*) free_days
 30  from available a
 31  group by to_char(a.datum, 'mm')
 32  order by to_char(a.datum, 'mm');
```

Result:

```
MONTH  FREE_DAYS
----- ----------
01            31
02            28
03            31
04            30
05            31
06            30
07            31
08             9   --> you said it should be 8; nope. August has 31 days
09            26
10            31
11            30
12            31

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to generate every day of the month; instead, you can split the rows you already have into separate months and then `UNPIVOT` and use analytic functions to find a cumulative count of when people enter and leave and use that to generate the free days (which will require you to generate significantly fewer rows than counting days of every month or year and no joins).

```sql
WITH split_months (check_in, check_out, max_check_out) AS (
  SELECT check_in,
         LEAST(check_out + 1, ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(check_in, 'MM'), 1)),
         check_out + 1
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT check_out,
         LEAST(max_check_out, ADD_MONTHS(check_out, 1)),
         max_check_out
  FROM   split_months
  WHERE  check_out < max_check_out
),
presence (prev_dt, dt, next_dt, change, num_present) AS (
  SELECT LAG(dt) OVER (
           PARTITION BY TRUNC(dt, 'MM')
           ORDER BY dt, change DESC, ROWNUM
         ),
         dt,
         LEAD(dt) OVER (
           PARTITION BY TRUNC(dt, 'MM')
           ORDER BY dt, change DESC, ROWNUM
         ),
         change,
         SUM(change) OVER (
           ORDER BY dt, change DESC, ROWNUM
         )
  FROM   split_months
  UNPIVOT ( dt FOR change IN ( Check_In AS 1, Check_Out AS -1 ) )
)
SELECT TRUNC(dt, 'MM') AS month,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN num_present = 0
         THEN COALESCE(next_dt, ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(dt, 'MM'), 1)) - dt
         ELSE dt - TRUNC(dt, 'MM')
         END
       ) AS num_free_days
FROM   presence
WHERE  num_present = 0
OR     ( prev_dt IS NULL AND num_present - change = 0 )
GROUP BY TRUNC(dt, 'MM')
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Name, Check_In, Check_Out) AS
SELECT 'Joey Zolomon',   DATE '2023-08-05', DATE '2023-08-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Hunter Zolomon', DATE '2023-08-15', DATE '2023-08-26' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Barry Allen',    DATE '2023-09-02', DATE '2023-09-05' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| MONTH | NUM_FREE_DAYS |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-08-01 00:00:00 | 9 |
| 2023-09-01 00:00:00 | 26 |

---

If you want to see the ranges of free days for each month then the final part of the query can be adapted to:

```
WITH split_months (check_in, check_out, max_check_out) AS (
  SELECT check_in,
         LEAST(check_out + 1, ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(check_in, 'MM'), 1)),
         check_out + 1
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT check_out,
         LEAST(max_check_out, ADD_MONTHS(check_out, 1)),
         max_check_out
  FROM   split_months
  WHERE  check_out < max_check_out
),
presence (prev_dt, dt, next_dt, change, num_present) AS (
  SELECT LAG(dt) OVER (
           PARTITION BY TRUNC(dt, 'MM')
           ORDER BY dt, change DESC, ROWNUM
         ),
         dt,
         LEAD(dt) OVER (
           PARTITION BY TRUNC(dt, 'MM')
           ORDER BY dt, change DESC, ROWNUM
         ),
         change,
         SUM(change) OVER (
           ORDER BY dt, change DESC, ROWNUM
         )
  FROM   split_months
  UNPIVOT ( dt FOR change IN ( Check_In AS 1, Check_Out AS -1 ) )
)
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN prev_dt IS NULL AND num_present - change = 0
       THEN TRUNC(dt, 'MM')
       ELSE dt
       END AS start_free,
       CASE
       WHEN prev_dt IS NULL AND num_present - change = 0
       THEN dt
       ELSE COALESCE(next_dt, ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(dt, 'MM'), 1))
       END AS free_end,
       CASE 
       WHEN prev_dt IS NULL AND num_present - change = 0
       THEN dt - TRUNC(dt, 'MM')
       ELSE COALESCE(next_dt, ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(dt, 'MM'), 1)) - dt
       END AS days
FROM   presence
WHERE  num_present = 0
OR     ( prev_dt IS NULL AND num_present - change = 0 )
```

Which outputs:

| START_FREE | FREE_END | DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-01 00:00:00 | 2023-08-05 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 2023-08-27 00:00:00 | 2023-09-01 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2023-09-01 00:00:00 | 2023-09-02 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2023-09-06 00:00:00 | 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | 25 |

---

From Oracle 12, you can also use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching to find the overlaps (and then the gaps before and after each overlap) and then can split into months and aggregate:

```sql
WITH find_overlaps (prev_free_start, free_end, free_start, next_free_end) AS (
  SELECT LAG(check_out + 1) OVER (ORDER BY check_in),
         check_in,
         check_out + 1,
         next_check_in
  FROM   table_name
  MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
    ORDER BY check_in, check_out DESC
    MEASURES
      FIRST(check_in) AS check_in,
      MAX(check_out) AS check_out,
      NEXT(check_in) AS next_check_in
    PATTERN (overlap* non_overlap)
    DEFINE
      overlap AS MAX(check_out) >= NEXT(check_in)
  )
),
unique_free_ranges (free_start, free_end) AS (
  SELECT COALESCE(free_start, TRUNC(free_end , 'MM')),
         COALESCE(free_end, ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(free_start, 'MM'), 1))
  FROM   find_overlaps
  UNPIVOT (
    (free_start, free_end) FOR before_after IN (
      (prev_free_start, free_end) AS 0,
      (free_start, next_free_end) AS 1
    )
  )
  WHERE before_after = 0 AND free_start IS NULL
  OR    before_after = 1
),
split_months (free_start, month_end, free_end) AS (
  SELECT free_start,
         LEAST(free_end, ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(free_start, 'MM'), 1)),
         free_end
  FROM   unique_free_ranges
UNION ALL
  SELECT month_end,
         LEAST(free_end, ADD_MONTHS(month_end, 1)),
         free_end
  FROM   split_months
  WHERE  month_end < free_end
)
SELECT TRUNC(free_start, 'MM') AS month,
       SUM(month_end - free_start) AS days_free
FROM   split_months
GROUP BY TRUNC(free_start, 'MM');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w7tsn2tX)